# Использование переменных сессии при заполнение формы php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, сессия

Есть веб-приложение php, в котором используется механизм авторизации и идентификации пользователя, основанный на использовании сессий. Пользователь заходит в приложение под своей учеткой, где заполняет форму, которая пишет данные в mysql db.

В БД есть поле, в которое записывается id пользователя, которое при отправке формы берется условно из `$_SESSION["user_id"]`.

Дело в том, что при длительном по времени заполнении формы на сервере периодически убиваются временные файлы с информацией о сессии, и при отсутствии дополнительных проверок в БД пишется `user_id = 0`,  что не есть хорошо. При добавлении проверки в скрипт на отправке формы выдается уведомление а ля "что-то пошло не так" и пользователю приходится авторизоваться заново и заполнять всю форму.

Как избежать подобных ситуаций?

Comment: куки еще делать......нет сессии - авторизуй по куки.

Comment: Т.е. механизм сессии в данном варианте использования не применим? Обычно предпочитал использовании сессии ввиду отсутствия мороки с безопасностью и т.д...

Comment: Я написал "куки еще делать"..... не вместо сессии..... а ЕЩЕ..... если убивается сессия по каким либо причинам - то ищем куку.

Comment: Это какого размера форма? 1) Разбить форму на меньшие куски, что бы не превышать времени в сессии. 2) Поднять длинну сессии до разумных пределов(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php). 3) Если человек открыл форму и пошел курить то заставить перелогиниться нормально!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не думаю что куки хороший вариант, так как больше возможности наделать дырок.

Comment: Если убивается сессия т.е. дропаются файлы в tmp, то можно еще переписать механизм хранения сессий при помощи session_set_save_handler ( http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-save-handler.php ) и использовать системы кеширования для хранения сессий, можно так же хранить сесии в БД в таблицах Memory. +Периодически обновлять сессию отправляя аякс запросы скажем каждые 3 минуты

Comment: @E_p да? ну вы это скажите разработчиком `yii2` тогда. А то они не в курсе, что это плохо

Answer (score 1):

> Дело в том, что при длительном по времени заполнении формы на сервере
>   периодически убиваются временные файлы с информацией о сессии

Эту проблему надо решить, тогда и данный вопрос будет неактуален и ещё десяток, с которыми вы *пока* не столкнулись.

*С настройками PHP по умолчанию такого не происходит!* Если сессия (т.е. сессионная кука или файл) пропадает из-за ваших настроек — проанализируйте что и зачем вы меняете и найдите другое решение.

Вы можете хранить user_id непосредственно в куки, но со временем жизни куки можно точно так же "накосячить". Так что советую не искать обходное решение, а вылечить болезнь.

**P.S.** Когда user_id неизвестен он, получается, [неавторизован](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) на добавление записей! Надо проверять такие вещи при обработке запроса.